# xlErrorChecks Enumeration Office 365/Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

In my current version of Excel, the enumeration of xlNumberAsText seems inconsistent with both the documentation [XlErrorChecks Enumeration (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841186.aspx) and prior usage recommended on SO.  It seems that particular error is Item 4; whereas previous posts about clearing this error using VBA have used a constant of 3.

[image]

Is this a bug in Excel 2016?  Or am I doing something incorrectly.

Here is code demonstrating the issue.  And if you examine the worksheet after running the code, it is apparent that the error is flagged, in Excel, as `NumberAsText` and not as `Inconsistent Formula`.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
Dim I As Long
Dim B As Boolean
Dim S As String
Dim R As Range

'Save current state
B = Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText

'Enable
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = True

Set R = Cells(1, 1)

With R
    .Clear
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = "1"
End With

For I = 1 To 10
    S = S & vbLf & I & vbTab & R.Errors(I).Value
Next I
S = Mid(S, 2)

'Restore original state
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = B

MsgBox S

End Sub
```

---

[image]

And also, in trying to clear the error box, I must use

```
R.Errors(4).Ignore = True
```

Neither `Errors(3)`, nor `Errors(xlNumberAsText)` will have any affect on the error box.

I've noted other inconsistencies with the enum and the documentation:

```
Inconsistent Formula: 5
Wrong Data Type:      2
```

I'm not going to bother to check the rest.  But I am going to try to report it to MS.  Thanks to those who confirmed this problem.

Comment: Behavior confirmed on my Win365 (32 bit) on Win10 64.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the same version as I have.  Seems like a bug, but I want to check the others also.

Comment: I tried it a couple of different ways and got the same thing. The UI shows the error but every time Errors(3) was false and Errors(4) was true.

Comment: @AlwaysData Thanks. Which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followup:  I reported this to MS via the Feedback option within Excel.  And after this morning's update, the problem seems to have been corrected.

[image]